# what means " Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA] signarure:..." in my output?

Tags: templates, glassfish, signature

I am making web application, and in my output "GlassFish Server 4.1.1" i can see

```
Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 58 CE 29 EA FC F7 DE B5   CE 02 B9 17 B5 85 D1 B9  X.).............
0010: E3 E0 95 CC 25 31 0D 00   A6 92 6E 7F B6 92 63 9E  ....%1....n...c.
0020: 50 95 D1 9A 6F E4 11 DE   63 85 6E 98 EE A8 FF 5A  P...o...c.n....Z
0030: C8 D3 55 B2 66 71 57 DE   C0 21 EB 3D 2A A7 23 49  ..U.fqW..!.=*.#I
0040: 01 04 86 42 7B FC EE 7F   A2 16 52 B5 67 67 D3 40  ...B......R.gg.@
0050: DB 3B 26 58 B2 28 77 3D   AE 14 77 61 D6 FA 2A 66  .;&X.(w=..wa..*f
0060: 27 A0 0D FA A7 73 5C EA   70 F1 94 21 65 44 5F FA  '....s\.p..!eD_.
0070: FC EF 29 68 A9 A2 87 79   EF 79 EF 4F AC 07 77 38  ..)h...y.y.O..w8
```

I am beginner and sorry if this is a stupid question. I used templates in my code which i think are free. Can this be because they are not actually free or what?

Answer (score 0):

This is only information about the SSL certificate which is used by Glassfish. For the normal usage you can safely ignore this log statement.

It is totally free to use.